# Image renaming program in C#/.NET 

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am working on a .NET program that is intended to iterate through a selected directory and allow the renaming of image files after displaying the images. I feel through my code that around 98% of the program is done, but I used a `while` loop to wait for the pressing of a button so as to allow for the renaming of the image file. Yet, the `while` loop freezes the program every time the `while` loop is iterated.

How can I either `system("pause");` like in C++ to have the `while` loop pause without freezing the program and creating an infinite loop or how can I have the `while` loop paused automatically until a button is pressed?

Here is a tidbit of the code for the loop:

```
paused = true;
bool X = false;
label2.Text = "please choose a file name and press next";
//while statement
while (X == false)
{
    if (paused == false)
    {
        //Renames filename
        string newFileName = filenameTextbox.Text;

        //Adds filename to selected directory where user wishes to send file to
        string outputFile = destinationDirectory + "\\" + intCounter + fileNameOfficial;

        //Pause statement to move to next operand..

        //Copies post iterated file to selected directory
        File.Copy(inputFile, outputFile, true);
        X = true;
    }
}
```

The code in its entirety is below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;


namespace recursionBitches
{

    public partial class fileSorter : Form
    {
        bool paused = true;
        public fileSorter()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void browseFrom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Warning dialouge for selecting a large file.
            MessageBox.Show("Warning, before selecting the origination file, it is important to note that choosing too large of a directory (for example, my documents or 'C://') more than likely will cause this program to freeze. ");
            MessageBox.Show("You have been warned");
            //Choose the originating dir path. This dir path is to be later sorted using recursion.
            //Once the originating dir path is chosen, it is added to the label above the button.
            if (fromBrowse.ShowDialog(
                ) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                this.originationLabel.Text = fromBrowse.SelectedPath;
            }
        }


        private void browseTo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Choose the send to dir path. This dir path is to later have the files that are sorted sent to it.
            //Once the to dir path is chosen, it is added to the label above the button.
            if (toBrowse.ShowDialog(
               ) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                this.sendingLabel.Text = toBrowse.SelectedPath;
            }
        }


        private void sortButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string fileExtension = "*" + fileExtensionTextbox.Text;
            //Check from path to ensure they are set to a user defined path.
            int intCounter = 1;
            if (originationLabel.Text != "From")
            {
                //Check to path to ensure it is set to a user defined path.
                if (sendingLabel.Text != "To")
                {
                    //Recursion stuff...
                    string sourceDirectory = fromBrowse.SelectedPath;
                    string destinationDirectory = toBrowse.SelectedPath;
                    //Sends origination path to function ae this is a function call. its num = 8675309... I think its name is Jenny.
                    recursiveRecursion(sourceDirectory, destinationDirectory, fileExtension, intCounter);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Message box that says it is required to
                    MessageBox.Show("You dun goofed");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Yup, it's a message box.
                //That was an unhelpful comment....
                /Aalmost as unhelpful as this comment
                // This is what happens when I program stoned.
                MessageBox.Show("You dun goofed");
            }

            //Grabs the path of the originating directory.
            //After the originating directory path is choosen, send the path to a recursion function
            //which will search the folders and sort the files in the dir. path.
        }


        private void originationLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Silly user, I am a label. I dont even click");
        }


        private void sendingLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Silly user, I am a label. I dont even click");
        }
        //Recursion function which grabs the directory path, uses a foreach loop to iterate through the files.
        //Whilst each file is iterated through, have the recursive function select the files by extension and copy
        //the files to another directory chosen by the user.
        private void recursiveRecursion(string sourceDirectory, string destinationDirectory, string fileExtension, int intCounter)
        {
            //Select files Path and stuff
            string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory, fileExtension);
            //foreach (string directoryName in directoryNames)
            string[] directoryNames = Directory.GetDirectories(sourceDirectory);
            //dir is the file name, as in for each file name in directory do the thing in this recursion loop thingy.
            foreach (string fileName in filenames)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (File.Exists(fileName))
                    {
                        //Don't use recursion. It is a file
                        //copy files here and stuff.

                        intCounter++;
                        //For the destination file ae dir2 to work, I need to get the file name from the file path.
                        //Currently dir is the file path.
                        //Enter code here to get the file name from the file path.

                        //Displays on label name of the file.
                        this.filesortTextbox.Text = "the file being copied is " + fileName;
                        //Gets filename from path

                        string fileNameOfficial = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
                        //Enters text of filename into filename textbox
                        filenameTextbox.Text = fileNameOfficial;

                        //For copying purposes, adds filename to originating directory path.
                        string inputFile = sourceDirectory + "\\" + fileNameOfficial;

                        //Assigns image from the origination directory.
                        Image img = Image.FromFile(inputFile);
                        // Shows image in the image viewer...
                        iteratedPicturebox.Image = img;
                        iteratedPicturebox.Width = img.Width;
                        iteratedPicturebox.Height = img.Height;

                        //Allows the user to change file name, after changing filename allows
                        //user to go to next file to rename. This is awesome for files...

                        paused = true;
                        bool X = false;
                        label2.Text = "Please choose a file name and press next.";
                        //while statement
                        while (X == false)
                        {
                            if (paused == false)
                            {
                                //Renames filename
                                string newFileName = filenameTextbox.Text;

                                //Adds filename to selected directory where user wishes to send file to.
                                string outputFile = destinationDirectory + "\\" + intCounter + fileNameOfficial;

                                //Pause statement to move to next operand..

                                //Copies post iterated file to selected directory.
                                File.Copy(inputFile, outputFile, true);
                                X = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //This really has an unknown pourpose, admittably keeping here for good luck...
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a valid file or directory.", fileName);
                    }
                }

                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    //What process failed you ask? Good question mate.
                    Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
                }
            }

            //Long story short for each directory contained in the list of directories.
            //Do the stuff listed in the foreach statement.
            foreach (string directoryName in directoryNames)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (Directory.Exists(directoryName))
                    {
                       //If this is a directory, send the thing through itself.
                       // MessageBox.Show("now going through the "+ directoryName + " directory");
                       recursiveRecursion(directoryName, destinationDirectory, fileExtension, intCounter);
                       this.directoryIterated.Text = "The Current Directory The Files Are being copied from is " + directoryName;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        private void fileExtensionTextbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void directoryIterated_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("I am a label. I don't even click");
            this.directoryIterated.Text = "You pressed me.";
        }

        private void kill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        private void filesortTextbox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("I am a label. I don't even click.");
            this.directoryIterated.Text = "You pressed me.";

        }

        private void iteratedPicturebox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("I am a picture box, I don't even click.");
        }

        private void nextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (paused == false)
            {
                paused = true;
            }
            else
            {
                paused = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're using a while loop that runs indefinitely to 'pause' the program. I'm not sure how well this will work, but try adding `Application.DoEvents();` inside that while loop and tell me how it goes

Comment: Well, yes, your program will freeze if it's executing that loop. While the UI thread is executing the loop, it can't very well respond to a button click. What exactly is the reason for the loop? Also, rather than your `recursiveRecursion`, take a look at `Directory.EnumerateFiles`, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458.aspx, and `Directory.EnumerateDirectories`, which will make your life somewhat simpler.

Comment: I would avoid having the processing loop at all.  Or do leave it, but make it bring up a modal dialog box for each input.

Comment: @mazzzzz: Using `Application.DoEvents()` is never the right thing to do.  Leave the UI thread for doing UI stuff.  Let the computations and other stuff run in separate threads, then you wouldn't have to resort to using that horrible method in the first place.

Comment: Trust me I know, but there is no way I'm going to explain a proper way to do this in a comment, and I don't have the time to write up a full explanation on why it is a horrible idea, so I was just making sure that was the issue first.  Running it async would be an option, but reordering the application so it worked off of events would be the best way.  Should have added that in my last comment though ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) for your processing loop. This allows you to process this on the background thread and won't freeze your main UI thread (which is what is happening)

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question though, since it was about interacting with the user, not doing work in the background.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to stop execution, I would display a dialog box:

1. Create form eg: `FileRenameDialog`.
2. Add public properties to form you can use to set From: text, etc.
3. Create instance of form. eg: `FileRenameDialog reuseme`
4. Whenever the user needs to make a selection, populate the text in the dialog.  eg: `reuseme.Source = "The current file being copied...";`
5. Display the dialog to the user as modal eg: `var dlgResult = reuseme.ShowDialog(this);`
6. Do what you need to with the result eg: `if (dlgResult == DialogResult.OK) {...do stuff with the properties of reuseme...}`